# Не работает функция mail

Tags: php, html

Есть скрипт на php с функцией mail. Она не срабатывает, хотя скрипт исполняется. Ошибка в формировании сообщения? Тогда как правильно? Дебаг не особо помог

```html
<?php

$headers='';

$subject='Заявка с сайта';

$to='почта';
$from='почта';

$name=('Имя: ' ($_POST['$name']));
$number=($_POST['number']);
$email=('Email: ' ($_POST['email']));

$massage='$name, $number, $email';
//$massage=urldecode($name, $number, $email);

mail($to, $subject, $massage, $headers);

header("Location: ./index.html");
?>
```

Comment: вы начните с того, чтобы результат функции проверить.

Comment: что вы подразумеваете по словами "дебаг не помог". что вы называете дебагом?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский что-что, по ф8 в лучшем случае прошел по каждой строке, посмотрел что не упало.

Comment: @teran не не не...надо чтоб ТС ответил.... некоторые дебагом называют echo м var_dump переменной.....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `print_r();die`  наше все :D

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: начните с  включения ошибок ↑↑↑  т.е. читайте все варианты............ а также.... смотрите что вернула сама функция mail